Azure Wordpress file permissions
I have seen a few questions similar to this on stack overflow but no clear answer so I am asking this again.
I have an azure Wordpress app service installed using azure default Wordpress template. Every folder and file in wwwroot is permission 777. I have run chmod 775 for folders and 644 for files but it has no effect. I try is -al to confirm and everything is still 777. How do I adjust these file permissions?
Edit:
See commands with no result:

Using find and chmod:


Check this doc for instructions on changing file permissions in WordPress.

I created Azure Wordpress app service using Azure default Wordpress template by following Ms Doc.
Thanks @Srinud for clear steps to change the file permissions in WordPress on Azure App Services.
I opened the kudu console by using below URL.
https://<AzureWordpressWebAppName>.scm.centralus-01.azurewebsites.net/

After that I clicked on the SSH and followed below steps.

To change the directory permission from 777 to 775, I ran the below command.

chmod 755 -R /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/

I ran the command below to see if the permissions changed.
ls -ltr /var/www/wordpress




See my updated pic above. I tried to do this from bash and also ssh panel but no effect.

Looking at your picture it doesnt look like you changed anything and your permission was already set to 755 for wp-content. Can you try to change uploads folder and let me know your results and update screenshot? Thanks!

@Qiuanz I will try and update.

Thanks. I think you will see its not as easy as that one post in MS made it sound. I have been searching and searching and hoping I am just missing something silly.

@Qiuzman I will try and let you know if there is any alternative solution.

@Qiuzman I edited my answer, please check once.

Okay so I see you switched to SSH. I have reproduced what you do and it does change the folders (except upload that doesnt seem changeable I guess). However, it does not do it recursively. I am trying to change every folder and subfolder to 755 and file to 644. Not sure why the command your doing isnt doing recurislvey because you have the -R. I tried this also: : find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \ & find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ; but it did not work. Also, how does /var/www/wordpress differ from the folder I was accessing /home/site/wwwroot/?

@Qiuzman /var/www/wordpress/ is the default directory for WordPress.

For site migrations MS reocmmends copying contents of other site into /home/site/wwwroot so its strange there exists 2 directories holding the wordperss files. Not sure I understand that. Could you confirm 2 things for me and I will accept this answer. Can you recursively change the folder/file permissions like my last comment indicates and confirm why you cannot change the upload folder and its stuck on 777?

@Qiuzman I am also unable to change the permission of the upload folder, the reason may be that it points to another directory.

Okay so I am not losing my mind! Were you able to recursively change all folder permissions to 755 and file to 644? theres thousands of folders so doing by hand would take way to long?

@Qiuzman Check this image.

I used that exact approach but for the entire wordpress directory. See what happens in my post with my updated picture. I am loosing my mind on this.

@Qiuzman Check these three images image1, image2, image3, I got three different outputs.

Thank you! I checked over all three. You see how inconsistent it is? It seems you were still unable to get the directories and files to all conform to 755 and 644 , respectively. So is it impossible and if so does this pose a security issue??

Also why is it performing this way? Its baffling me because every example I have tried to do this on a linux server just doesnt seem to work in app services!

so do this TWICE chmod -R a=r,u+w,a+X /var/www/wordpress seems to do the trick for me BUT the next day it goes back to 777 lol. Also sometimes running it the other directories change back to 777 as well. I have no idea what i am doing at this point.

Btw if you go back into your app service I am sure you will see your permissions are reset to 777 by now. Can you confirm this?

@Qiuzman yes, it is set back to 777.

@Qiuzman I tried to find any documentation related to this issue, but I couldn't find anything useful.

I also could not find anything useful. I am glad it’s not just me.  I am going to leave this open To see if we get any more useful answers .
